# Как получить список открытых окон Safari в python?

Tags: python, safari

Делаю программку которая помогает анализировать игру в шахматы. Для этого мне нужно чтобы, если открыт сайт lichess.org, python скрипт находил адресс и созранял в переменную.

Есть ли команда которая дает список открытых оконо в сафари?

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ответ сам на [stackoverflow.com/questions/8552823](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552823/get-safari-and-chrome-opened-tabs-on-mac-with-appcelerator)

```
import appscript
urls = appscript.app('Safari').windows.tabs.URL()
```